# Delegate "System.Func<Testproj.pInfo,int,bool> does not take 1 argument"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, delegates

```
    MembershipUser userobj = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentuserid = (Guid)userobj.ProviderUserKey;
        List<pInfo> pobj = new List<pInfo>();
        pobj = (from pid in db.pInfoes.Where(c => c.UserIdentity == currentuserid)
                orderby pid.pId descending
                select pid).ToList();
        return View(pobj);


   (c => c.UserIdentity == currentuserid) : Error -- Delegate   "System.Func<Testproj.pInfo,int,bool> does not take 1 argument"
```

I have gone through many similar issues on stak-overflow but not able to solve it. Need some guidance on delegate's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misleading description to my question.. The problem was not the delegate code but the argument type that I was passing to the entity framework query. As UserIdentity is of type Unique-identifier and pInfo had StoreGeneratedPattern="none" in edmx file for this type.
I had to change the StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity Type in edmx file and it worked.
The following post and some of the above comments helped me to nail down this issue.
Thanks for all the concern and your precious time.
http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/

Answer (score 1):

The arguments of your func `c => c.UserIdentity == currentuserid` don't match what's required, `System.Func<Testproj.pInfo,int,bool>`. You need an `int` argument too. I assume you already are expecting `c` to be `Testproj.pInfo`, so you just need to add an argument for the `int`. The return type of the fund is `bool`. Try:

```
.Where((c, i) => c.UserIdentity == currentuserid)
```

Comment: Delegate   "System.Func<Testproj.pInfo,bool> does not take 2 argument"

Comment: Hmm, that matches the code you had originally. If you change `(c, i) =>` back to `c =>` does the original error message (the one in the question) come back?

Comment: yes it does come back..System.Func<Testproj.pInfo,int,bool> does not take 1 argument

Answer (score 1):

Is UserIdentity  an integer type, if not, you will need `UserIdentity.Id=currentuserid`